# Magento Newsletter form not working

Tags: magento, newsletter

I am trying to add a newsletter signup form to my Magento site creativeinfusion.com.au/shop
The problem is that the email address doesn't get added to the subscribers list.

I have tried both of these below in my content block.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}

{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Neither one adds the subscribers email address to the CMS. I am assuming that the code above is not linking to the correct file?

Comment: We have the same. ANy ideas yet?

Answer (score 5):

This code:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Works great for V-1.7.x.x.

Answer (score 1):

The correct line to add to the cms is the following:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

Because newsletter/subscribe is the correct block. I added it in a clean Magento installation and it worked fine.

What is happening for you? Is the subscription form not showing at all? Is it not posting? Is it not storing the entered email adresses?

Since it works out of the box it sounds like it could be some other module or js/css that interferes with the process.

Comment: The subscription form is showing but it is not storing the entered email address.

Answer (score 1):

`{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}` <- This works for me.